# ruby on rails using fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, fixtures

I am using fixtures in testing.

For example:

```
post bookings_path, params: { journal: { from_account_number: "1",
                                         from_account: "Test",
                                         from_amount: "12",
                                         to_account_number: "2",
                                         to_account: "Test2",
                                         to_amount: "12"
      } }
```

Is it possible to replace

```
from_account_number: "1",
from_account: "Test",
from_amount: "12",
to_account_number: "2",
to_account: "Test2",
to_amount: "12"
```

with one fixture call?

Comment: You should use factories. FactoryGirl is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

Of course, assuming all that params are from one object and use rspec with it, you can do this:

```
describe '#POST to bookings_path' do
  before do 
    @booking = bookings(:one)
  end

  it 'should be successful' do
    post bookings_path, params: { journal: @booking.attributes }

    expect(response.status).to eq(201)
  end
end
```

If for example they are from one same model but from 2 different objects (like account_1 and account_2), then just substitute with this:

```
    data = @account_1.attributes
    post bookings_path, params: { journal: data.merge(@account_2.attributes) }
```

Comment: How can I use rspec?

Comment: by adding gem 'rspec-rails' to your gemfile. What test framework are you using? Is it minitest? If so, I will update my answer

Comment: I am using minitest.

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrong approach to solve the issue.

Now, I simply defined a method in the test_helper.rb with:

```
eigenkapital_buchen{
  post bookings_path, params: { journal: { from_account_number: "1",
                                         from_account: "Test",
                                         from_amount: "12",
                                         to_account_number: "2",
                                         to_account: "Test2",
                                         to_amount: "12"
      } }
}
```